# Infinite loop scrolling using UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, infinite-loop

I am trying to make an infinite loop image gallery app. I did it by setting up a UIScrollView inside which I inserted UIImageViews. 
I am able to load 4 images and swipe between them, but the problem I have is how to implement the infinite scroll, so that after the last image, the first one appears and opposite.

As I am newbie in Swift, I don't know how to handle this problem nor where to start. I will appreciate any suggestion, example or link on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the peace of my code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

    let scrollViewWidth: CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight: CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.height

    let numPics: Int = 3

    let imgOne = UIImageView()
    let imgTwo = UIImageView()
    let imgThree = UIImageView()
    let imgFour = UIImageView()

    var arrPics = [imgOne, imgTwo, imgThree, imgFour]
    var arrSlide = ["slide1.png", "slide2.png", "slide3.png", "slide4.png"]

    for i in 0...numPics {

        arrPics[i] = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,scrollViewHeight * CGFloat(i),scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

        arrPics[i].image = UIImage(named: arrSlide[i])

        self.scrollView.addSubview(arrPics[i])

        }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width, self.scrollView.frame.height*4)

}
```

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial which shows the best way on how to create an endless loop between pages. You can find a detailed tutorial, and download a working project from github here:
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/ NOTE: My approach was wrong because I used UIViewController, instead of using a UIPageViewController.

Comment: Thanks for linking my blog post, Igor. Regarding your approach, this is very doable using a `UIViewController`: the successor to that tutorial ended up wrapping it in a `UIViewController`, that way other UI elements could be added on top of the `UIPageViewController` (in this case, custom page dots and a next button). https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/11/move-uipageviewcontroller-dots/

Comment: @Jeff You're welcome! Thanks to you and your great post I found a way to solve my issue finally. Keep doing a great job, I'll probably need more help from you in the future :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what will solve your problem, just adjust the controller to go in vertical slide view and load the resources at your will.

[Link](https://github.com/igroomgrim/Infinite-scroll-with-uipageviewcontroller/blob/master/Infinite-scroll/PageViewContainerViewController.m)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a scroll view but either a table view or a collection view.

The delegates of both classes want a cell count from you. Then give the delegates an insane number of cells, a number so high that it is totally unlikely that any human being will ever scroll to reach the end. Something like 9999999 cells. This is no problem for such classes because in the background implementation they do not create really this high number of cells but only maximal the number of cells which could be visible at the same time on the screen. The cells in fact are reused. So when cells are falling out at the bottom those cells are going to be reused at the top and vice versa. As a last point is: set the starting point in the middle of such a high number, something like 5555555. I think that is the easiest solution if you are not going to implement a full image recycling algorithm like they did.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can try to implement your solution. Do you have any code example perhaps? @darko

Comment: No, but this is all you need to get the idea. Search for tutorials on UICollectionView or UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat!
let numPics: Int = 4


override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()

  scrollView.delegate = self
  self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

  let scrollViewWidth: CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
  scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height



  let imgOne = UIImageView()
  let imgTwo = UIImageView()
  let imgThree = UIImageView()
  let imgFour = UIImageView()
  let imgFive = UIImageView()


  var arrPics = [imgOne, imgTwo, imgThree, imgFour,imgFive]
  var arrSlide = ["slide1.jpeg", "slide1.jpeg", "slide1.jpeg", "slide1.jpeg","slide1.jpeg"]

  for i in 0...numPics {

     arrPics[i] = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,scrollViewHeight * CGFloat(i),scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

     arrPics[i].image = UIImage(named: arrSlide[i])

     self.scrollView.addSubview(arrPics[i])

   }

  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width, self.scrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(numPics+1))

}

 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
 {
     scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width, self.scrollView.frame.height * scrollViewHeight )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Timer you can use infinite scrolling like below

```
func showview() {

    if(videosimageslider.isEmpty) {
        // print("Empty Array")
    } else {
        // print("Not Empty ")
        // print(videosimageslider.count)

        for var index=0; index<videosimageslider.count; index++ {
            if let url = NSURL(string: videosimageslider[index]) {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                    if let imageUrl = UIImage(data: data) {
                        let  myimageview:UIImageView = UIImageView()
                        // myimageview.image = imageUrl
                        let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageUrl: NSURL!) -> Void in
                            //println(self)
                        }

                        // let url = NSURL(string: "http://yikaobang-test.u.qiniudn.com/FnZTPYbldNXZi7cQ5EJHmKkRDTkj")
                        myimageview.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: block)
                        myimageview.frame.size.width = imagewidth
                        myimageview.frame.size.height = imageheight
                        myimageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
                        myimageview.frame.origin.x = xscrollpos
                        myimageview.frame.origin.y = 5
                        scrollview!.addSubview(myimageview)
                        xscrollpos += imagewidth
                        scrollviewcontentSize += imagewidth
                        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollviewcontentSize, height: imageheight)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        scrollingTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "newStartScrolling", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        scrollingTimer.fire()
    }
}

// call the timer function //
func newStartScrolling() {
    var currentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
    currentOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffset.x+3, currentOffset.y )

    if(currentOffset.x < scrollview.contentSize.width - 500) {
        scrollview.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
        currentOffset = CGPointMake(0, currentOffset.y )
        //scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0);
    } else {
        scrollingTimer.invalidate()
        showview()
    }
}
```